# Print specific value from a list in dictionary in python

Tags: python

Im trying to print specific value in this dictionary compiled of several list.

```
the_dic = {'k1':[1,2,3,{'tricky':['oh','man','inception',{'target':[1,2,3,'hello']}]}]}
```

Expected output: hello

Can i expand from this simple code below?

```
print(the_dic["k1"])
```

Comment: @GalodoLeste https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 2):

You can keep indexing further by referring to the specific index (of the list) `[3]` or further keys in the dictionary!

This works because the result of each indexing or key reference returns the inner value, which exposes its own methods for indexing or referring to its keys (or a single value, ending your chain!) depending on the inner type

Continuing the chain little further

```py
>>> d = {'k1':[1,2,3,{'tricky':['oh','man','inception',{'target':[1,2,3,'hello']}]}]}
>>> d["k1"]
[1, 2, 3, {'tricky': ['oh', 'man', 'inception', {'target': [1, 2, 3, 'hello']}]}]
>>> d["k1"][3]
{'tricky': ['oh', 'man', 'inception', {'target': [1, 2, 3, 'hello']}]}
>>> d["k1"][3]["tricky"]
['oh', 'man', 'inception', {'target': [1, 2, 3, 'hello']}]
```

Offering a simpler example, it may be clearer still

```py
>>> d = {'a': {'b': [1,2,3]}}
>>> d['a']['b']      # list referenced by key 'b' within key 'a' of d
[1, 2, 3]
>>> d['a']['b'][0]   # first member of the very innermost list
1
```

Answer (score -1):

I think for your desired output your final code will be:

```
the_dic = {'k1':[1,2,3,{'tricky':['oh','man','inception',{'target':[1,2,3,'hello']}]}]}

print(the_dic['k1'][3]['tricky'][3]['target'][3])
```

**Result:**

```
hello
```

Answer (score -2):

A helper recursive function such as this should do the trick:

```py
def get_last_val(d):
    if isinstance(d, list):
        return get_last_val(d[-1])
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return get_last_val(d.popitem()[1])
    return d
```

Example:

```py
>>> get_last_val(the_dic)
'hello'
```

Comment: Your assumption that the OP always wants the last item in a sequence is unwarranted.

Comment: also _beware_ Python versions before 3.6 (*3.7) have unordered dict keys, so they may not be in the order they were inserted and depends instead on the implementation (the vastly most common of which giving them by their hashed order)